# What is more safe - keep network connected or do connect-disconnect

Tags: security, tails, connection

If I need to go away for a while, then should I turn off cable/wifi, or to leave Tails connected?
First option looks better because physically disconnected, but multiple connect-disconnect can cause some additional edge effects and risks?
(sorry if stupid question)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. If you turn it off you save electricity. If you leave it on you don't. Neither will necessarily affect your anonymity.

What's best is to understand exactly [how Tor works](https://2019.www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en).